# How is bash not completing this loop and only processing 1 item unless I don't call script X?

Tags: bash, gradle

I have the following loop that WORKS...

```
# Build all modified projects
echo "$PROJECTS_TO_BUILD" | while read PROJECTS; do
    log "Calling build-projects.sh ${PROJECTS}"
    #$DIR/build-projects.sh ${PROJECTS}
done;
echo "I get here in both looping cases"
```

There is a list of projects on EACH line (separated by newline character).  Notice I have one line in that loop commented out.  Then I have this loop that doesn't work...

```
# Build all modified projects
echo "$PROJECTS_TO_BUILD" | while read PROJECTS; do
    log "Calling build-projects.sh ${PROJECTS}"
    #$DIR/build-projects.sh ${PROJECTS}
done;
echo "I get here even though the loop only executed the first thing"
```

I trimmed the build-projects.sh script down until I found the issue in that one where I call gradle(which is in another loop).  If I don't call gradle, everything works and if I call gradle, the loop doesn't work.

I just noticed the gradle wrapper has this at the top while the other scripts are in bash.  Does this matter?

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
```

Another trick I tried was just adding & and that works but it needs to block.  I wonder, is there an easy way to fork and block and that would fix it perhaps?

Comment: It sounds like this is your issue:   https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089

Comment: Does `gradle ... < /dev/null` cause the script to work again? If so I'd be interested to know what kind of configuration you have that causes gradle to drain stdin (and I'm sure future readers would as well)

Comment: Well, I found a hack which was backgrouding it, then waiting on the pid, then checking status and that fixed it for now.  I was in a hurry so haven't had a chance to dig back into it deeper.